# Apostrophes in Grammar

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english, apostrophe, subcontinental-english

In the sentence- "Jessie's and Nora's dogs are lovely".
Do we really have to put apostrophes on both the names?

Comment: Potentially, it changes the meaning between [Jessie and Nora]'s dogs to [Jessie's dogs] and [Nora's dogs]. Do they each have dogs, or do they both have the dogs together?

Comment: so is the statement correct or wrong? what if both have same dog?

Comment: It depends what you mean. If both have all the dogs, then only one *'s*; if they both own different dogs but you are referring to all of the dogs, then two *'s*. As I said in my earlier comment, and as noted in the answers at the linked question.